# Windows 7 recovery partition not working

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, boot, recovery-partition

I have a Samsung N150 laptop. It originally had Win 7 Starter on it. I have upgraded it to Windows 8.

I now want to revert back to Windows 7. But when I start the netbook and press <kbd>F4</kbd> [recovery], nothing happens. (i.e. it carries on and boots Windows). Pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> does take me to the BIOS setup however.

I have checked the recovery partition is still there, and appears to be OK. Is there some other way to access the recovery partition?

Comment: Did you verify the partition still exists?  The good news you should be able to download your own ISO of Windows 7 and install it that way.

Comment: If I go to windows 8 partition manager it clearly shows the Recovery partition at the front

Comment: How large is that partition.  Because GPT/EFI disk have a small 100-200MB partition normally that isn't the OEM partition.

Comment: I have: 20GB Recovery Partition; 100MB System NTFS; 212GB C:\ NTFS